# Get the date of next saturday in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

How would you get the date of the the first saturday that occurs after today in Objective-C for iOS?

Comment: [Which Saturday does "next" refer to?](http://oxtweekend.com)

Comment: The first Saturday after today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will guide you through the process of manipulating calendar dates:

[Calendrical Calculations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1)

Answer (score 11):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger todayWeekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];

enum Weeks {
    SUNDAY = 1,
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY
};

NSInteger moveDays=SATURDAY-todayWeekday;
if (moveDays<=0) {
    moveDays+=7;
}

NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
components.day=moveDays;

NSCalendar *calendar=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate* newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];

NSLog(@"%@",newDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

`[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString: @"next Saturday"]`

---

Edit: Starting in OS X 10.9 and iOS 8, you can do this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *saturday = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
saturday.weekday = 7 /* Saturday */;

NSDate *nextSaturday = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:now matchingComponents:saturday options:0];
```

Comment: From the official documentation: This method (dateWithNaturalLanguageString:) supports only a limited set of colloquial phrases, primarily in English. It may give unexpected results, and its use is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Bavarious - I did see that. It's a lot simpler than what I was going to do and it works in my case.

Comment: Even if it supports only a limited set of colloquial phrases in English, "next Saturday" will work in any application.

Comment: That call is not in the iPhone SDK (article was tagged iphone).

Comment: It works in the iOS SDK, but is not recognized as part of it.

Comment: If it's actually in the iOS SDK but isn't in the documentation then I expect it will be treated as a private API by the app review team, so you won't get in the app store. Also have you actually run it on a device? It's possible it isn't actually there and the simulator is using the OS X implementation.

Comment: I've run it on the device, but it causes my code sense to stop working in Xcode, odd. It *is* in the documentation.

Comment: application shows compile time error with `dateWithNaturalLanguageString`

Comment: This is OS X only and has been deprecated in 10.10.

Comment: @AlexsanderAkers great answer. nextDateAfterDate is not documented yet but is a brilliant addition to NSCalendar. It also knows how to search backwards which makes it double useful.