# How can i get date of a coming day - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios6.1

If I say `upcoming monday` then how can I get date of `upcoming monday`?

Like, today is `Thu, 04-04-2013` than how can I get what date will be on coming `wednesday`?

Hope I am able to clarify you.

Similar question was asked here but I'm not able to understand this:

[Get the date of next saturday in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579294/get-the-date-of-next-saturday-in-objective-c)

Comment: should i give solution or you will search?

Comment: please give solution.

Comment: Don't tell us that you're unable to understand the answer to your exact question.  Tell us what part of the answer you don't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger todayWeekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];

enum Weeks {
    SUNDAY = 1,
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY
};

NSInteger moveDays=WEDNESDAY-todayWeekday;
if (moveDays<=0) {
    moveDays+=7;
}

NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
components.day=moveDays;

NSCalendar *calendar=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate* newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];

NSLog(@"%@",newDate);
```

Comment: I like your answer most. It is easier to understand. But If today is `Friday` than for `next friday` it gives `today's date`! Trying to rectify this. Thanks

Comment: just replace `if (moveDays<0)`  by `if (moveDays<=0)`

Answer (score 1):

Just to irritate Anoop ;) :

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval nowInterval = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
int days = (int)(nowInterval / (24 * 60 * 60));
int today = (days + 4) % 7;
NSDate* saturday = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:nowInterval + (6 - today) * 24 * 60 * 60];
NSLog(@"saturday = %@", saturday);
```

Comment: I got irritation...full body...this weekend will visit doctors. As per many people specially "Viki" they say never do 60*60*24 as all days are not having 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours, also some daylight etc. Whenever 2-3 months back, i used this trick I got downvotes in bulk. But You are Hot and every one likes you, so upvote :)

Comment: if i want to find some other day, do i need to change 4, 7, 6 or what?

Comment: I leave that as an exercise for the user.  Figure out what the algorithm is.

Comment: Good good. At least tell to me ;)

Comment: It's really not complicated, though you need a Jan 1970 calendar to get started.