# Inserting a comma for integers when there are three digits added everytime to the textfield in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, textfield, nsmutablestring

I need to add comma separating numbers into three digits without white spaces and if total digits are under three, then no comma added.

For example:

```
2984 => 2,984
297312984 => 297,312,984
298 => 298
```

How do I solve this?

Tried this:

```
if([textfield.text length] > 3)
{
 NSMutableString *stringtext = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textfield.text];
 [stringtext insertString:@"," atIndex:0];
}
```

Abt after starting, started to think if there is a better solution? This is because there will be a lot of if-else statements.

Welcome to any suggestion.

Comment: If you want to honor locale, you should perhaps rephrase your question and ask for on-the-fly update of input in textfield that would insert thousands group separator for you. And for that NSNumberFormatter is good choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I've come up with: just set the delegate of the text field, and implement the following method accordingly:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.text.length % 4 == 3) {
        if (string.length != 0) {
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", textField.text, string];
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thanks, that's what I thought.

Comment: This the differnce between you and me, If I assume and solve, i get at least 3 downvotes. hahaa. But for you always +5. :D

Comment: @AnoopVaidya (you should have seen me being massively downvoted at some C++ questions...)

Comment: @lakesh Thanks :) You'll get here quick :)

Comment: @Viral: My all time dowvotes shows 26, and i think 20 will be for questions.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811007/how-can-i-get-date-of-a-coming-day-objective-c/15812383#15812383), if that would be my answer, surely -5. Ohhh in this answer I started getting dnvotes....congrats me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use NSNumberFormatter,

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // this line is important!

NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2000000]];

[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **NSNumberFormatter**:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *commaString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:yourIntegerValue]];
NSLog(@"---> %@",commaString);
```

Or by **string manipulation** `<This is not the best way>`:

```
NSMutableString *mutString=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"123456789"];

NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray new];
for (NSInteger i=1; i<=mutString.length/3; i++) {
    NSInteger index=[mutString length]-i*3;
    [array insertObject:[mutString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 3)] atIndex:0];
}
if (mutString.length!=mutString.length/3*3) {
    [array insertObject:[mutString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, mutString.length%3)] atIndex:0];
}
NSString *commaString=[array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"--> %@",commaString);
```

Comment: Excuse me, but isn't the requirement that the text in the text field be updated live?

Comment: I don't know, even in thequestion it is not mentioned.

Comment: Right, I just deduced from the target object being a text field... whatever ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this following function

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Method : ChangeNumberIntoCommaSeparatedStringDec
    // Method to convert number into comma separated string
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -(NSString *)ChangeNumberIntoCommaSeparatedStringDec:(double)num
    {

            NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:num];
            NSNumberFormatter *frmtr = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
           //here locale as applied to do not change the formatter values after changing the device locale
            [frmtr setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
            [frmtr setGroupingSize:3];
            [frmtr setGroupingSeparator:@","];
            [frmtr setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
            [frmtr setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
            [frmtr setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
            NSString *str=[frmtr stringFromNumber:number];
            [frmtr release];
            return(str);        
    }
```