# Repeat alarm on weekly basis

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification, alarm, nscalendar

I am implementing the alarm application. I am stuck with the logic. How  to repeat the alarm on weekly basic, mean if user selected the sunday than alarm will be rang on every sunday...
Here is my code.

```
-(void) repeataftersevendays: (NSString *) day
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    sunday = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                       value:4
                                      toDate:[NSDate date]
                                          options:0];;
    NSLog(@"value is %@",sunday);

}
```

and here is my notification fire code.

```
-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate
{

 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Time to wake Up";
    localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me";
    localNotif.soundName = @"Tick-tock-sound.mp3";
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotif.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitDay;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use repeat interval parameter of [NSLocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/). set it to [NSWeekCalendarUnit](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/)

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
```

Comment: this will repeat the alarm daily but i want that if user select thursday than it will repeat tomorrow and upcoming thursday and so on... @user3729525

Comment: "NSWeekCalendarUnit" Week Unit will enable the alarm to repeat weekly not daily.

Comment: yes its working .. but today is wednesday and if user select the alarm day is friday than how i can achieve that. @Tina

Comment: You can get the date of next friday and then multiply number days in to set firedate. Please Refer to ::: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579294/get-the-date-of-next-saturday-in-objective-c